# How can I obtain variable values for the START and END of a day, given the current DateTime?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, datetime

```
now = DateTime.now
```

What I want, is given the current DateTime, is to populate variables for the `start_of_day` and `end_of_day` relative to eastern time.

So for example, I'm posting this at approximately 12:15 ET.

`now = DateTime.now` is returning "Sun, 24 May 2015 16:15:00 +0000".

My end goal is to have variables `start_of_day` and `end_of_day` that represent 00:00:00 ET, and 23:59:59 ET. Right now, ET is EDT (Eastern Daylight Time between March and November), and therefore it's 4 hours different from UTC. [From Novemeber to March, ET will be EST (Eastern Standard Time) and 5 hours different from UTC]. So right now, with EDT, we would want values of

```
start_of_day = "Sun, 24 May 2015 04:00:00 +0000"
end_of_day = "Mon, 25 May 2015 03:59:59 +0000"
```

How can I achieve variables with these dates, given `DateTime.now`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out these methods:

```
now = DateTime.now
now.beginning_of_day
```

and

```
now.end_of_day
```

These will return the appropriate DateTime objects you need.

Docs:

http://apidock.com/rails/DateTime/beginning_of_day
http://apidock.com/rails/DateTime/end_of_day